# What's the best way to import external data into Firebase?

Tags: xml, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My company has contracted an event scheduling vendor to help us plan out our event schedules. Our conference teams will be inputting date/time/location/description data (and more) into their system. I'm tasked with building the front end that that data will show on our event website. That data is unfortunately only available to me as poorly structured XML. Additionally, I only have access to do things on the client side.

I'm pretty new to Firebase, but I'm pretty sure it would be good if I can create collections from the XML. All of the articles and tutorials I've seen either:

- reference how to manually import data via Firebase's console
- use your web app to allow users to input/change data

For this project, I want to create my collections based on the XML from the vendor.

What do you suggest would be the best way to go about this? Or is Firebase not the right platform for my problem?

Comment: Is this Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database? Also, have you worked with NoSQL databases before and understand how to structure that data for your queries? Also, have you tried using one of the online utilities to convert a snippet of your XML to JSON? Like [XML to JSON](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.XNRTjC-ZNR4). Once it's in JSON you *can* import it into the Firebase Realtime Database, if that's what you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For this project, I want to create my collections based on the XML from the vendor.

This is how you should it, create a collection based on the information you have in that XML. If you're looking for a magic button that can convert your XML file data to Cloud Firestore, there isn't one! And as far as I read, Firebase creators won't create one because it's quite impossible. So unfortunately, you'll need to convert the XML file yourself, by parsing the entire file and add the data to Cloud Firestore according to the schma that is most likely to be used for your app's use-case.

Comment: I'm good with parsing the XML myself and using JS to push to Firebase in a better-structured collection. I guess the question is that I need a way to have that run regularly to update Firebase when the conference team makes changes in the Vendor's system.

Comment: Why not to use only a single source, Firestore? If it's mandatory to have two sources, then you should to create a system that observs the changes in your first database and add them in Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I have to have the 1st source (vendor) and the 2nd would be Firestore. I'm just not that clear on the best way to build the system to observe the changes or where to put it.

Comment: If you need both, then this is your only option. Without seeing your 1st source (vendor) is hard for someone to tell you exactly what to do. But knowing the you already have a XML file, for sure you need to parse it and then add that data to Cloud Firestore. One thing to remember, everything in Firestore is about the number of read and writes, so getting your entire database from source one and pushing it to Cloud Firestore doesn't seem to be a feasible option.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about the number of reads/writes. Knowing the normal web traffic that could get problematic. I'll most likely be better just parsing it and putting directly to the website and not including Firebase in the mix.

Comment: You're very welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Javascript utility running in Node on your workstation to parse the XML data into manageable collections. If you're using Firebase's Realtime Database, you can coax the data into JSON format then import it via Firebase Console. If you're using Firebase's Firestore, I don't think there's any way to just import a collection of data. Using a client utility, you can connect to Firestore with your Javascript utility and push your collections' documents individually.

Authentication could be an issue. Ideally, you'd get a service account key with which your script can authenticate and use the Firebase Admin-SDK. This would give you the most flexibility in being able to manage your data in Firestore (or any other Firebase service).

You could also use Firebase's client libraries within your utility script and authenticate as a client account assuming you have a user/password account or some other method of sign-in setup. Oh, and you'd also have to ensure the Firestore security rule are setup properly to allow your utility's data push. (The Firestore rules *could* be setup to allow anybody to upload data, but it's certainly not recommended!)

You mentioned you only have access to client side... It'd be pretty hard to do everything you need when it comes to testing your script, validating your uploaded data/structure, and managing your Firestore's security rules without access to the Firebase console. Maybe you could setup a separate (development) Firebase project for yourself so you can work out all the necessary utility code, authentication issues, security rules, etc. Then, if somebody else is "holding the keys" to the production Firebase project, you can be specific about what you need setup to make things work.

Comment: You can import to Firestore data that's been exported from Firestore. You'd do this if you were restoring a backup of your Firestore data or transferring the data from one project to another. Looking at a set of exported data, and lacking instructions describing the necessary format of data to be imported, this import capability is not a reasonable solution for uploading new data as Milton is proposing.